# Sum two query set in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have two models, Quote and Post.
I want two send this to my template:

```
posts = Post.objects.order_by("-submitted_time")
quotes = Quote.objects.order_by("-submitted_time")

thing = posts + quotes
```

but some of two QuerySet not support. How can I send posts and quote to the template?

suppose I have two Post and two Quote in database like this:

```
   post 1        submitted_time:2010/2/12
   post 2        submitted_time:2010/2/8 
   quote 1       submitted_time:2010/2/9
   quote 2       submitted_time:2010/2/13
```

I want to send a list like `[quote2, post1, quote1, post2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
from itertools import chain
thing = list(chain(posts, quotes))
```

To order it the way you want:

```
import operator
from itertools import chain

thing = list(chain(posts, quotes))
thing = sorted(thing, key=operator.attrgetter('submitted_time', reverse=True)
```

Or

```
thing = sorted(thing, key=operator.attrgetter('submitted_time')
```

depending on which you want

Comment: Thank's. I want reverce of thing list that you say.

Comment: then get rid of the `reverse` parameter at the end. Check the edit